# Wrapping an arrow function inside a normal function

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions

My goal is that I'm trying to pass the *this* context from a normal function to an arrow function but I keep getting undefined.

I know that *this* in a normal function behaves dynamically and determined by how the function was called. The *this* inside an arrow function follows lexical scoping rules to determine its value. However, when I call printWrapper() on line 16, *this* is set to the car object, so when I further call printThis(), as per the lexical scoping rules, it should print the car object, but in my case the *this* object being printed on line 2 is the global object.

```
printThis = () => {
  console.log(this); // prints the global object
}

var car = {
  year: 2015,
  printThis: printThis,
  printWrapper: printWrapper
}

function printWrapper() {
  console.log(this); // prints the car object
  printThis();
}

car.printWrapper();
```

Comment: Lexical scoping works with respect to the static structure of the source code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable) . Note that the crucial thing is the lexical structure of the function *definition* not the function *invocation* (which would be dynamic scoping).

Comment: MDN explains it pretty well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: lexical scoping means that it inherits the value of `this` from the scope where the function was defined, not where it's called.

Comment: And since the function is defined in the global scope, it gets the global `this`.

Comment: When you use arrow functions it no more holds the reference of the place from where it is called. Here the scope of arrow function is global, hence you will get the global object

Comment: @Pointy I think I might've confused lexical and dynamic scoping. I guess moving the arrow function inside printWrapper() and then calling it there will print me the car object.

Comment: @JohnColeman not a duplicate as I know how arrow functions and normal functions work. I mixed them up when using it together.

Comment: @Frosty That question has become the goto duplicate target for anyone confused about `this` and arrow functions (in much the same way that "Is floating point math broken?" has become the standard dup target for many floating-point questions). A duplicate target doesn't have to be exact to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, the context of an arrow function is the same context of the scope where it was defined, not the context from where it is called.

If you need to "pass the *this* context" to a function you could use `Function.prototype.bind()`, it will return a new function with the first passed argument assigned to `this`. `Function.prototype.call()` or `Function.prototype.apply()` works similarly by calling the function in place with the desired `this`.

Please note that this methods will work only with normal functions. Arrow functions are anonymous and their context cannot be explicitly set.

```js
function printThis() {
  console.log(this); // prints the car object
}

var car = {
  year: 2015,
  printThis: printThis,
  printWrapper: printWrapper
}

function printWrapper() {
  console.log(this); // prints the car object
  printThis.call(this);
}

car.printWrapper();
```

Comment: I'm aware of and have used bind(), but my goal here was to try to pass the *this* of printWrapper() to an arrow function which is printThis().

Answer (score 0):

So I mixed up lexical and dynamic scoping and assumed that printThis() will be able to access the *this* of printWrapper(). As [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) mentioned that lexical scoping works with respect to the static structure of the code which means that moving the printThis() function inside printWrapper() will allow its own *this* to be accessible from printThis().

```
var car = {
  year: 2015,
  printWrapper: printWrapper
}

function printWrapper() {
  console.log(this); // prints the car object
  printThis = () => {
    console.log(this); // also prints the car object, *this* now refers to the scope of printwrapper
  }
  printThis();
}

car.printWrapper();
```